# How to exit a script when a exception appear?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have the next script kafka connect-standalone.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF)

set -e    

if [ $# -lt 1 ];
then
        echo "USAGE: $0 [-daemon] connect-standalone.properties"
        exit 1
fi

base_dir=$(dirname $0)

if [ "x$KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    export KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$base_dir/../config/connect-log4j.properties"
fi

if [ "x$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
  export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx2G"
fi

EXTRA_ARGS=${EXTRA_ARGS-'-name connectStandalone'}

COMMAND=$1
case $COMMAND in
  -daemon)
    EXTRA_ARGS="-daemon "$EXTRA_ARGS
    shift
    ;;
  *)
    ;;
esac

exec $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class.sh $EXTRA_ARGS org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone "$@"*
```

When I run the script, and the mqtt server is not running, it print the next exception: `ERROR [mqtt-kafka-123456789] Connection to Broker failed! (com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector:132)` but the script doesn't exit, it continues running.

Is anyway to detect this exception and exit the script when this appear?

Comment: Have you tried adding `set -e` at the start of your script?

Comment: @ssemilla Yes I have added but it doesn't exit. The problem is that the exception is not of the script, is from a Jar the script is using.

Comment: Whatever solution there might be involves `kafka-run-class.sh`; the script you show no longer exists once you use `exec`.

Comment: @chepner I have added `set -e` to the `kafka-run-class.sh` script to. but it doesn't exit

Comment: `set -e` is only relevant if the command producing the error message has a non-zero exit status, which it either does not or you run in in a context that causes `set -e` to ignore it. You'd have to show the relevant part of `kafka-run-class.sh` for us to comment further.

Comment: @chepner This error is throwing by a JAR that the script calls, so the relevant part of the `kafka-run-class.sh` is where it is calling the JAR?

Comment: Yes. Nothing in the code you currently show appears to be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but the script doesn't exit

That means that you need to parse the script output as it comes. Below I use a fifo as a buffer between the process and your script.

```
# fifo creation
tmp=$(mktemp -u)
trap 'rm -rf "$tmp"' EXIT
mkfifo "$tmp" 

# we start the command that writes to our fifo
# the command process is started in background
# this is our precious child
(  
    $(dirname $0)/kafka-run-class.sh \
        $EXTRA_ARGS \
        org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone \
        "$@"*
) > "$tmp" &
# remember childs pid
child=$!

# this is "watcher" / "parent" process - it checks if the child behaves
# for each line the child outputs...
while IFS= read -r line; do
   # print the line as is on stdout
   printf "%s" "$line" 
   # ...we check if the line has the string ERROR in any way
   if 
       case "$line" in
       *ERROR*) true; ;;
       *) false; ;;
       esac
  then
      echo "Error command printed out error line $line" >&2
      # we kill our child
      kill "$child"
      # let's wait for our child to exit
      wait
      # let's exit ourselves.
      exit 1
  fi
done < "$tmp"
```

1. I guess that when errors occur, the output from the command will output `ERROR`. The `case` check for ERROR in the output stream. If it does, it returns `true` status thus enters `then ...`, it if doesn't, it returns `false` status, thus will not enter the `then ...`. The return status of `case` command is equal to the last executed command. Alternatively you can `[[ "$kafka_run_class_output" =~ ERROR ]]` when having bash>=4 with `[[` command.
2. That `"$@"*` on the end of kafka command line arguments looks very suspicious.
3. I just kill my child, but in case your child is not behaving when receiving the TERM signal, be sure to send it SIGKILL.
4. Your script has /bin/sh shebang, not bash. If you have bash, use bash arrays for passing arguments to other scripts. It's better to `EXTRA_ARGS+=(-daemon $EXTRA_ARGS)` and then `kafka-run-class.sh ...  "${EXTRA_ARGS[@]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the script that does not exit after an error is the kafka-run-class.sh. The connect-standalone.sh script has no reason to keep running after kafka-run-class.sh is done. You would want to capture the output and check for the exact error message, then react accordingly. Either modify the kafka-run-class.sh script to handle this error, or add something like the following to connect-standalone.sh:

```
OUTPUT=$(./kafka-run-class.sh)

if [ "$OUTPUT" == "ERROR [mqtt-kafka-123456789] Connection to Broker failed!" ]
then
    echo $OUTPUT" was an error"
else
    echo $OUTPUT" was fine"
fi
```

The $(COMMAND) captures the output of kafka-run-class.sh. The if statement checks that the output of that command matched the error you want to quit on.

Comment: If `$OUTPUT` contains spaces (and it does), you test command `[ $OUTPUT ` will fail miserably on syntax errors. Always quote your variables. The `==` is a bash specific alias for `=` and the `test` command uses `=` for string comparison. Using backticks \` for command substitution is [deprecated](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Comment: Thanks! I made some changes.